# display data in UITableView on view navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

i have 2 views-view1 and view2, one for entering data and another for displaying the entered data.
I am able to display the entered data in view2 in labels. But how to display the data in a UITableView. Following is my code to display the data:

view2.m

```
@synthesize details; //details is an object of NSMutableArray.
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    textLabel.text = self.name;
    lblCity.text = self.city;
    lblGender.text = self.gender;


}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [details count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"creme_brelee.jpg"];
    return cell;
```

i debuuged and found that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called.

Where am i getting wrong? How do i solve it?

Comment: Did you set your `dataSource` and `delegate` of the tableView to your object?

Comment: sorry but i am new to ios, how do i set them?

Comment: if u have taken table in xib then set its delegate methods to files owner. see this http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iOS_4_iPhone_Table_View_Application_%28Xcode_4%29

Comment: go to your xib file and select your table and right click on table and attach the delegate and datasource to file owner

Comment: @z22 Go to Interface Builder, rightclick on your UITableView, and you will find two outlets, `delegate` and `dataSource`. Click in the little circle and drag the blue line to your files owner / your object.

Comment: thanks it worked. Sorry for being so silly but can you all please let me know the importance and functionality of this? i mean of delegate and datasource. We just have to drag and connect it to file's owner. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a NSMutableArray of display Data in to `UITableViewCell` like below and don't forget to declare UITableView delegates in **.h** file `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` and also connect your UITableView IBOutlet in your **xib** and also connect the delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrCategorisation=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"DataOne",@"DataTwo",@"DataThree", @"DataFour",@"DataFive",nil];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrCategorisation.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            cell.textLabel.text=[arrCategorisation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

your Table load data like:-

[image]